# Drawing a diagonal line of my matplotlib scatterplot?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to draw a diagonal line on my figure to demonstrate how my data compares to someone else's, so I want a line representing 1:1 relationship. I'm trying to use plt.plot to do the line between two points but there is no line on my plot. This is my code + the figure. Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

```
plot23 = sns.regplot(x = Combined['log10(L/L_solar)'], y = Combined['logLum'], 
fit_reg=False).set_title('Figure 23: Comparing luminosities')
plt.xlabel('logL from my data', fontsize=13)
plt.ylabel('logL from Drout', fontsize=13)
plt.axis((4, 6, 4, 6))
plt.plot([0,0], [6,6], 'k-')
plt.show()
plot23.figure.savefig("figure23.png")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake in using plt.plot. The syntax is

> plt.plot(xarray,yarray, ...)

.
This should be :

```
plt.plot([0,6], [0,6], 'k-')
```

Answer (score 2):

To draw infinite lines under a specified angle, e.g. 45deg through the origin at (0,0) you can use

```
plt.axline( (0,0),slope=-1,linestyle='--',color='red')
```

This line will span the full axes box regardless the data extremes and you don't have to first determine the axis limits or data limits.

This is a generalization of *plt.axhline()* and *plt.axvline()*, which are used to draw infinite length horizontal and vertical lines.

Ref: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pyplots/axline.html